# How do I render a collection of objects with Nustache?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mustache

I'm attempting to use [Nustache](https://github.com/jdiamond/Nustache) so that I can share rendering templates between back end and front end code in an ASP.Net web app.  It's working fine when I just pass an object to a template, but I can't figure out how to get it to render a collection.  So if I have a template like this:

```
{{#RenderItems}}
  <th data-warning="{{WarningLevel}}" data-limit="{{LimitLevel}}">{{TotalHours}}</th>
{{/RenderItems}}
```

Then I want to pass in a collection of objects and get out a set of `th` elements.

Things I've tried:

- Creating a class with the properties `WarningLevel`, `LimitLevel` and `TotalHours`, adding objects to a `List` and passing that directly: `Nustache.Core.Render.FileToString(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("my.template"), ListOfObjects)`
- Doing the same thing, except creating an anonymous class: `Nustache.Core.Render.FileToString(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("my.template"), new { RenderItems = ListOfObjects})`
- Instead of a list, using a `Dictionary` containing the same objects
- Using a dictionary of dictionaries - so each item is itself a dictionary with the properties named above

The only way it renders anything at all is if I use an anonymous class, but I can't get it to populate the template with the named items whatever I do.  I'm sure I'm missing something fairly obvious here, as I assume this should be straightforward, but the documentation says 'look in the code and the tests' but I can't work out which test is actually dealing with this scenario.  Can someone either point me in the right direction, or provide some example code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was able to get this working with the following class and controller action:

```
public class Person {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}

public ActionResult Index() {
    var people = new List<Person>() { 
        new Person { Name = "Albert Adams", Email = "albert@email.com" },
        new Person { Name = "Bob Becker", Email = "bob@email.com" },
        new Person { Name = "Charles Charles", Email = "charles@email.com" }
    };

    ViewData["People"] = people;

    ViewResult viewResult = View();
    viewResult.ViewEngineCollection = new ViewEngineCollection { new NustacheViewEngine() };

    return viewResult;
}
```

And then Index.nustache:

```
{{#People}}
    <p>{{Name}} - {{Email}}</p>
{{/People}}
```

Note that I pulled the latest changes from the Nustache repo this morning.

Comment: OK, thanks - how easy would that be to translate into standard ASP.Net?  I suppose I could try just creating a `ViewData` object?

Comment: I would have to look into it. I've only ever used Nustache with MVC, and I'm not certain how reliant it is on MVC-only features like ViewData.

Comment: I defined a dictionary object like this: `var RenderItems = new Dictionary<string, List<FooterRenderItem>>();` then pass my list in with the key, and that worked :)